# How to pass coordinates as arguments to a function?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, function-calls, zelle-graphics

The following is my code and when executed I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

This is my code:

```
def drawUpperCaseT(win, location1):

    letterT = Text(Point(location1), "T")
    letterT.setSize(30)
    letterT.draw(win)

def main():

    #1. Create Graphics Window
    win = GraphWin("My Initials", 600, 600)
    win.setCoords(0,0,100,100)
    location1 = (15,50)

    drawUpperCaseT(win, location1)

    #Capture Mouse to Close
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

When I put the code from the function in the `main` method it works. However when I try to implement it separately and pass `location1` as the argument to `drawUpperCaseT`, I get the error. It seems that maybe the y coordinate is getting lost or something. Can someone please explain what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: `location1` is a tuple. You're passing a single tuple to `Point`. Does it actually take a single location tuple as an argument, or does it expect separate x and y arguments?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see easily from Ducking, the Point constructor doesn't take a tuple. Instead it requires separate x and y parameters: `Point(x, y)`

You can either replace the location parameter with two individual parameters; like so:

```
def drawUppercaseT (win, x, y):
```

Or you could extract the tuple members; like so:

```
... Point(location1[0], location1[1]) ...
```

Or you could *flatten* the tuple during the call:

```
... Point(*location1) ...
```

I recommend flattening because  (1) it's cool; (2) tuples make more sense than separate coordinate values; and (3) it's cool!